# ccny_rgbd runtime symbol lookup error

Tags: ros, ccny-rgbd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Checked out this revision: https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_rgbd_tools/commit/88b1210524a32487f3538a5b7d28f2bbf3f6472e

Applied this patch: https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_rgbd_tools/issues/3

Compiled, everything is fine.

When I start nodes `visual_odometry_node` or `keyframe_mapper_node` I see the symbol lookup error appearing at run time:

```
[ INFO] [1361108695.958712716]: Starting RGBD Keyframe Mapper
/home/pavel/ros/ccny_rgbd_tools/ccny_rgbd/bin/visual_odometry_node: symbol lookup error: /home/pavel/ros/ccny_rgbd_tools/ccny_rgbd/lib/libccny_rgbd_registration.so: undefined symbol: _ZN9ccny_rgbd26removeInvalidDistributionsERKSt6vectorIN5Eigen6MatrixIfLi3ELi1ELi0ELi3ELi1EEESaIS3_EERKS0_INS2_IfLi3ELi3ELi0ELi3ELi3EEESaIS8_EERKS0_IbSaIbEERS5_RSA_
[visual_odometry_node-1] process has died [pid 30803, exit code 127, cmd /home/pavel/ros/ccny_rgbd_tools/ccny_rgbd/bin/visual_odometry_node __name:=visual_odometry_node __log:=/home/pavel/.ros/log/32aaa392-7908-11e2-8df2-00179a7bfadb/visual_odometry_node-1.log].
log file: /home/pavel/.ros/log/32aaa392-7908-11e2-8df2-00179a7bfadb/visual_odometry_node-1*.log
```

Ubuntu 12.04, GCC 4.6.3, ROS Fuerte.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55401/ccny_rgbd-runtime-symbol-lookup-error/) by [Spym](https://answers.ros.org/users/1256/spym/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2013-02-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2013-02-17**:
I applied the patch you submitted. This looks like an Eigen link error, possibly against typedef std::vectorEigen::Matrix3f Matrix3fVector. Could you run visual_odometry_node in a debugger?

**Comment by [Spym](https://answers.ros.org/users/1256/spym/) on 2013-02-18**:
Ivan, why do you think the error is against this typedef? I have no idea why not, just curious. (I just submitted the relevant issue on Github, patch included)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, the library `ccny_rgbd_registration` uses the symbol `ccny_rgbd::removeInvalidDistributions(...)`, which is defined in anonther library `ccny_rgbd_util`. I explicitly linked `ccny_rgbd_registration` with `ccny_rgbd_util`, and problem is gone.

I barely understand why it wasn't working when there was no direct linkage between these libraries. Maybe this symbol was sort of optimized out because executable file wasn't using it directly? But I've tried to build executables with -O0, and this didn't help.

---

Originally posted by [Spym](https://answers.ros.org/users/1256/spym/) with karma: 32 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0